# Exchange won't start after AD restore

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003

We have restored our active directory from a backup and now exchange won't start for some reason. The service that won't start is the Microsoft Exchange Information Store. It comes up with this message: `Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start.`.

I am guessing this has something to do with permissions but am not really sure where to start looking. I have perused various articles on the internet but am not sure the best place to start.

This is the error in the event log: `Process INETINFO.EXE (PID=1636). Topology Discovery failed, error 0x80040931.` I have looked up the ID but I don't really understand what the problem is.

EDIT: When trying to start the windows service attendant service this error is in the event viewer: `Unexpected error Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. Facility: Win32 ID no: 8007052e Microsoft Exchange System Attendant  occurred.` If I could reset this password (or at least see which user it is) I would be in a good starting place.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: There should be more event log entries than that.  Did anything change about the domain controller, and is it functioning correctly?

Comment: What service(s) failed to start? You should be able to sort the list of services by Startup Type and see which ones aren't started.

Comment: Microsoft Exchange Information Store. I went through all the dependencies and found that Exchange System Attendant wasn't started. When I try to start it, it says it started and stopped for some reason. All the dependencies of System Attendant are started. Only other one is EXFIS which I can't seem to find anything for.

Comment: So what account is the system attendant running as?  Look in service manager to see what account it is running  as

Comment: It says local account. I am not sure where to look to see what username / password could be incorrect ...

Comment: run services.msc then right click on the service and click properties

Answer (score 3):

Try running the Exchange BPA to figure out what broke and where. It's available here:

https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22485

Comment: Have run all checks and thay have come back with green ticks.

Answer (score 2):

The dependency error is telling you that the information store failed to start because a service that it depends on isn't running.  The first thing I would do is look to see what services it depends on and which hasn't started.  Then debug that service.

I don't see the need to re-run forest & Domain prep unless you restored from an AD backup taken before Exchange was installed.

It might be helpful to understand why you needed to restore AD.

Comment: The server died so I remounted a backup HD and restored the AD.

Answer (score 2):

Have you gone through this Microsoft KB article? It describes your problem pretty well so I imagine it'll describe the solution well too:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919089

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run the active directory ForestPrep and DomainPrep tools again in order to restore your active directory settings.

On your Exchange 2003 CD run

```
 E:\setup\i386\setup /ForestPrep,
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124110(EXCHG.65).aspx

then run

```
E:\setup\i386\setup /DomainPrep,
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997526(EXCHG.65).aspx

Comment: Right Ok. That was the next thing I was going to try. Do you know if exchange is on a seperate disk when installing windows 2003 SBS? I have 4 disks but none say Exchange ..

Comment: Nevermind, running the forest prep now. Will update when I know more.

Comment: how did that go?

Comment: Didn't seem to help :(